# JS window.close() let IE hang

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer

for reason I won't bore you with, I'm writing an asp.net application that must open some pages in new browser windows.

I managed to open them within a postback (don't ask why, I just needed to) with this code:

```
script = String.Format(@"window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"");", url, target);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), "Redirect", script, true);
```

Now I have new windows each one with a button that should close it. I have simply an `onclick="window.close()"` (but that prompts me when I'm closing the browser) or `window.open('','_self','');window.close()` (horrible, I agree but it's the only way I found to avoid the JS prompt)

On firefox it works perfectly but on IE7 (the browser our customers have) after 2-3 times I use that button to close the window I can't open other windows (in both cases, with or without the JS prompt). With the method above it does nothing, and with a `<a href="mypage.aspx" target="_blank">click me</a>` a new window is opened but hangs on loading (it doesn't even calls the Page_Load).

What could be the cause? How can I solve this?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I'm using MS Ajax in most of the pages, and that may be the reason that forces me to use `window.open('','_self','');` before `window.close()`
I don't know if this could cause also the hanging of IE

Comment: Is this a `<button>` or an `<input`>? It might be that a postback is canceling the `window.close` action.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain very well. Don't focus on the closing part, it works, the window closes, I only added to explain what I do.
The problem is that after 2-3 times that I successfully close, I can't open any more windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to a solution:

on the attribute assignment there was a `return false;` missing.

Now it works perfectly with `"window.open('','_self','');window.close();return false;"`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ignore that, it does still prompt the user - sorry!

For your first issue about closing the window, have you tried:

```
self.close();
```

Not too sure about the hanging issue though, I use window.open() and have never experienced issues in IE7.

Comment: I tried self.close(), window.close(), top.close(), <any other name for the current window>.close()
but the result it's the same. maybe I should add to the question the fact that I'm also using MS Ajax..